# programming to add a Google Sheet to someone's Drive by selecting their name in the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a system for work for when I select from a list of people that I am the sales rep for, filling out the sheet on a copy.

Just seeing if theres also a way such that when I choose my name, it also adds that sheet to my own Drive.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve]. Many of us may actually write a script for an op but we'd prefer it if you try it yourself first.  At this point your question is rather vague.

Comment: [Edit] to add more information. Do not add them as answers. They'll be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You weren't really clear as to what you wanted but this sort of script might be what your looking for.  If not, sorry.

```
function saveSelected() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Employee List');
  var data=sh.getRange(sh.getActiveCell().getRow(),1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var sObj={name:data[0],ssId:data[1],driveId:data[2]};
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(sObj.driveId);
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById(sObj.ssId);
  file.makeCopy(folder);
}

function loadSideBarButton() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<input type="button" value="Save Selected Row" onClick="google.script.run.saveSelected()" />');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}

function onOpen() {
  loadSideBarButton();//When you click this button saveSelected will be called and it will save the spreadsheet for the employee that you have selected with your cursor.  You just have to have selected the correct row.
}
```

The above scripts work with the following data structure.

[image]

Of course, you must be given full access to your employee folders.